# Is cProfile betraying me?

Tags: python, profiling, protocol-buffers, pyzmq, cprofile

I wanted to know why my `pyzmq` and `protobuf` based messaging ping-pong is much slower than expected, so I used `cProfile` to inspect the script you find at the end of this post.

```
protoc --python_out=. rpc.proto
python -m cProfile -o rpc.pstats ./test_rpc.py
```

returns

```
3.604 sec for 10000 messages, 360.41us/m, 2774 m/s
```

and

```
python -m pstats rpc.pstats 
rpc.pstats% sort tottime
rpc.pstats% stats 10
```

gives me (just for the client process):

```
         619163 function calls (618374 primitive calls) in 3.779 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 580 to 30 due to restriction <30>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    10002    2.658    0.000    2.658    0.000 {method 'recv' of 'zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket' objects}
    10002    0.088    0.000    0.088    0.000 {method 'send' of 'zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket' objects}
    10001    0.060    0.000    3.654    0.000 ./test_rpc.py:36(rpc_set)
    10002    0.058    0.000    3.457    0.000 ./test_rpc.py:32(zmq_reply)
    80016    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 {method 'write' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
    10002    0.056    0.000    0.424    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py:781(InternalSerialize)
    30004    0.054    0.000    0.137    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py:453(setter)
    20002    0.051    0.000    0.058    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/type_checkers.py:113(CheckValue)
    10002    0.050    0.000    0.055    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py:839(IsInitialized)
    10002    0.050    0.000    0.148    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py:577(ListFields)

...
```

The strange thing about this is: `recv()`/`send()` from `pyzmq` seem to consume about **2700 ms** while `protobuf` only consumes about **250 ms**.

But that's not true!

If I leave away the `protobuf` part, the same process only consumes about **1350 ms** (-65%) on the same system. (I didn't add the `pyzmq`-only script but you can just send a couple of bytes instead of the serialized data)

These extra 65% are attributed by nearly 100% to `pyzmq` which are actually consumed by `protobuf`.

**Question:** What's going on here? How can I profile my script in a way that points me to `protobuf` rather than `pyzmq` in this case?

In order to reproduce the date you have to have `protobuf-python` and `python-zmq` installed. Here are the script used for this experiment:

test_rpc.py:

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import subprocess
import zmq

import rpc_pb2  # must be generated first

if '--server' in sys.argv:
    print('zmq_protobuf_rpc_server')
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

    request = rpc_pb2.rpc_request()
    reply = rpc_pb2.rpc_reply()

    while True:

        request.ParseFromString(socket.recv())
        if request.type == rpc_pb2.rpc_request.SET:
            value = request.value
        elif request.type == rpc_pb2.rpc_request.GET:
            reply.value = "value"
        socket.send(reply.SerializeToString())
        if request.type == rpc_pb2.rpc_request.QUIT:
            break

else:
    def zmq_reply(req_msg, rep_msg, socket):
        socket.send(req_msg.SerializeToString())
        rep_msg.ParseFromString(socket.recv())

    def rpc_set(req_msg, rep_msg, socket, name, value):
        req_msg.type = rpc_pb2.rpc_request.SET
        req_msg.name = name
        req_msg.value = value
        zmq_reply(req_msg, rep_msg, socket)

    def rpc_get(req_msg, rep_msg, socket, name):
        req_msg.type = rpc_pb2.rpc_request.GET
        req_msg.name = name
        zmq_reply(req_msg, rep_msg, socket)
        return rep_msg.value

    print('zmq_protobuf_rpc')
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-u', __file__, '--server'])
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556")  # IPC would be a bit faster

    request = rpc_pb2.rpc_request()
    reply = rpc_pb2.rpc_reply()

    # wait for the server to be responsive
    rpc_set(request, reply, socket, 'hello', 'hello')

    N = 10000

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        rpc_set(request, reply, socket, 'name', str(i))
    t = time.time() - t
    print("%.3f sec for %d messages, %.2fus/m, %d m/s" 
          % (t, N, t / N * 1000000, N/t))

    request.type = rpc_pb2.rpc_request.QUIT
    zmq_reply(request, reply, socket)

    p.wait()
```

rpc.proto:

```
package rpc;

message rpc_request {
    enum RpcType {GET = 0; SET = 1; QUIT = 2; }
    required RpcType type = 1;
    required string name = 2;
    optional string value = 3; }

message rpc_reply {
    optional string value = 3; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to measure the process_time and not the system_time which is measured by default. This is done by using the custom timer function for your profiler, e.g. time.process_time().

Example:

```
import cProfile
import time
import pstats
import io

pr = cProfile.Profile(time.process_time)

pr.enable()

time.sleep(1)
for i in range(0, 1000):
    print("hello world")
time.sleep(1)
pr.disable()

s = io.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print(s.getvalue())
```

The print-function consumes most process_time and the stats will show that. 
If you don't pass time.process_time() as timer function, stats will show that the sleep function uses most of the time.